# $V\otimes V=\text{Sym}^2(V)\oplus\text{Alt}^2(V)$ as $\text{GL}(V)$-representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. $\text{GL}(V)$ acts on $V\otimes V$ via $f.(x\otimes y):=f(x)\otimes f(y)$. Define $$\text{Sym}^2(V)=\text{span}\{x\otimes y+y\otimes x| x,y\in V\}$$ and $$\text{Alt}^2(V)=\text{span}\{x\otimes y-y\otimes x| x,y\in V\}.$$

I want to show that $V\otimes V=\text{Sym}^2(V)\oplus\text{Alt}^2(V)$ as $\text{GL}(V)$-representations.

First I have shown that $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ and $\text{Alt}^2(V)$ are invariant subspaces of $V\otimes V$: This is easy as it is enough to show this on elements $x\otimes y\pm y\otimes x$ and $$f.(x\otimes y\pm y\otimes x)=f(x)\otimes f(y)\pm f(y)\otimes f(x).$$

But I have problems to show that the intersection is trivial and need help with this please.

If we have shown the trivial intersection part, are we done? Or what is a direct sum of $\text{GL}(V)$-representations?

Comment: The finite group $C_2$ acts on $V \otimes V$ by permuting the factors, and this action commutes with the $GL(V)$ action. A $C_2$ representation is the direct sum of its $+1$ eigenspace and its $-1$ eigenspace; now show that these are $\text{Sym}^2$ and $\text{Alt}^2$. This is a very special case of what is called Schur-Weyl duality.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way without using this duality?

Comment: I'm not using Schur-Weyl duality, just explaining what it reduces to in this special case, which is very elementary; the representation theory of $C_2$ is not at all complicated to understand.

Comment: But  I don't understand why you are concernin the $S_2$ and not the $\text{GL}(2)$ action, Is my way wanting to show that this intersection is trivial wrong? If no: Why is this intersection trivial?

Comment: The intersection is trivial because $\text{Sym}^2$ is the $+1$ eigenspace of the symmetry $x \otimes y \mapsto y \otimes x$, and $\text{Alt}^2$ is the $-1$ eigenspace, and the only vector which is in both the $+1$ eigenspace and the $-1$ eigenspace is zero. The $S_2$ action is important because it commutes with the $GL(V)$ action, which means that the eigenspaces of the $S_2$ action are $GL(V)$-invariant (exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be any vector space (over a field of characteristic not equal to $2$; ignore this if you don't know what it means) on which the cyclic group $C_2$ of order $2$ acts: write $g$ for the generator of $C_2$ acting on $W$. Then I claim that $W$ has a natural direct sum decomposition

$$W \cong W_1 \oplus W_{-1}$$

where

$$W_1 = \{ w \in W : gw = w \}$$

is the $1$-eigenspace of $g$ and

$$W_{-1} = \{ w \in w : gw = -w \}$$

is the $-1$-eigenspace of $g$. This direct sum decomposition comes explicitly from writing every vector $w$ as the sum of its "even" and "odd" parts

$$w = \frac{w + gw}{2} + \frac{w - gw}{2}.$$

The intersection of $W_1$ and $W_{-1}$ is trivial because if $gw = w$ and $gw = -w$, then $w = -w$, so $w = 0$. This is all a special case of a more general result about how to decompose representations of any finite group.

Now, $C_2$ acts on $V \otimes V$ for any vector space $V$ via the symmetry

$$g(v \otimes w) = w \otimes v.$$

> **Exercise 1:** Show that the $1$-eigenspace of this action is $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ and that the $-1$-eigenspace is $\text{Alt}^2(V)$.
>
> **Exercise 2:** Show that the fact that the $C_2$ action above commutes with the natural $GL(V)$ action implies that the $1$-eigenspace and $-1$-eigenspace of $C_2$ are $GL(V)$-invariant.

Answer (score 1):

To present Qiaochu's answer in a slightly different way, define a linear map $T: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ on pure tensors by $T(v \otimes w) = w \otimes v$ and extend linearly. A good name for this operator would be a "flip": it interchanges the sides of the tensor product.

You can show that $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ is contained in the $1$-eigenspace of $T$, and that $\mathrm{Alt}^2 V$ is contained in the $(-1)$-eigenspace of $T$, which gives you that $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V \cap \mathrm{Alt}^2 V = 0$.

Now all that's left is to show that $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V + \mathrm{Alt}^2 V = V \otimes V$, which can be done by taking any element on the right hand side and writing it as a sum of a symmetric and antisymmetric part.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. Thank you for this other view! The latter part follows directly from $x\otimes y =1/2 (x\otimes y + y\otimes x + x\otimes y - y\otimes x)$. So I won't need to take a general element from $V\otimes V$, i.e. a linear combination of pure tensors. And why this is now a direct sum not only of vector spaces but of representations? Because the involved vector spaces are invariant?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means to have a direct sum of representations.

Comment: Thanks :)......